# Migrate From Xen LVM to Citrix Xen

Tags: virtual-machines, lvm, migration, xen

I need to migrate some production vm's from Xen 4.2 to Citrix Xen 7.1. I have very little experience with Xen. The VM disks are LVM, see below info.

One possible solution might be to do the following but I am not sure:

```
qemu-img convert /dev/myvg/mylv -O vmdk myvolume.vmdk
```

Does anyone know the best way to migrate these Xen vm's?

Info:

```
xx-vm1:~ # xl info
host                   : xx-vm1
release                : 3.0.76-0.11-xen
version                : #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 08:21:43 UTC 2013 (ccab990)
machine                : x86_64
nr_cpus                : 4
max_cpu_id             : 7
nr_nodes               : 1
cores_per_socket       : 2
threads_per_core       : 2
cpu_mhz                : 2992
hw_caps                : bfebfbff:20100800:00000000:00000180:0000e4bd:00000000:00000001:00000000
virt_caps              : hvm
total_memory           : 16378
free_memory            : 5988
sharing_freed_memory   : 0
sharing_used_memory    : 0
free_cpus              : 0
xen_major              : 4
xen_minor              : 2
xen_extra              : .2_04-0.7.5
xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_32 hvm-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_64
xen_scheduler          : credit
xen_pagesize           : 4096
platform_params        : virt_start=0xffff800000000000
xen_changeset          : 26064
xen_commandline        : vga=mode-0x31a dom0_max_vcpus=2 dom0_vcpus_pin dom0_mem=2048M
cc_compiler            : gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]
cc_compile_by          : abuild
cc_compile_domain      :
cc_compile_date        : Fri Jun 14 12:22:34 UTC 2013
xend_config_format     : 4
```

..

```
xx-vm1:~ # virsh dumpxml xx-zcm
<domain type='xen' id='2'>
  <name>xx-zcm</name>
  <uuid>5e29bcc9-0dc8-6487-9577-e60b3a0a6497</uuid>
  <description>None</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <bootloader>/usr/bin/pygrub</bootloader>
  <bootloader_args>-q</bootloader_args>
  <os>
    <type>linux</type>
    <cmdline> </cmdline>
  </os>
  <clock offset='utc' adjustment='reset'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='phy'/>
      <source dev='/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-32027001378a8a714'/>
      <target dev='xvda' bus='xen'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='file'/>
      <source file='/install/SLES-11-SP3-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso'/>
      <target dev='xvdb' bus='xen'/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:16:3e:36:ec:44'/>
      <source bridge='br0.104'/>
      <script path='/etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge'/>
      <target dev='vif2.0'/>
    </interface>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target type='xen' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='xen'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' keymap='en-us'/>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

..

```
xx-vm1:~ # vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               GW
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               249.97 GiB
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              7999
  Alloc PE / Size       7999 / 249.97 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               wiLucJ-CEwG-PXyd-nLpw-Jygb-NYAG-9c8FCG

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               xx-ns
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               55.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              14079
  Alloc PE / Size       14079 / 55.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               hVxpBm-tXPD-bo7a-CPZz-zREz-44SO-OkGnfR
```

..

```
xx-vm1:~ # lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/GW/GW
  VG Name                GW
  LV UUID                KvZ6BU-2oJH-Secu-HvRA-LbcW-I8Og-8y1803
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xx-smtp, 2014-07-23 18:47:18 -0700
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                249.97 GiB
  Current LE             7999
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/xx-ns/data
  VG Name                xx-ns
  LV UUID                lR1ctY-5gg2-gwlR-PUyC-xJVe-SH6M-sIc0Bq
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xx-vm1, 2018-05-09 12:42:01 -0700
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                55.00 GiB
  Current LE             14079
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```